# Using pd.xlsxwriter to conditionally format an entire row based on a single cell in that row

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
 writer = pd.ExcelWriter(
        f"~/{datetime.today().strftime('%Y.%m.%d')} - Report.xlsx",
        engine="xlsxwriter",
        date_format="dd/mm/yyyy",
        datetime_format="dd/mm/yyyy",
    )
worksheet = writer.sheets["Sheet1"]
comma_format = workbook.add_format(
        {"num_format": "#,###;[Red](#,###);-", "bold": True}
    )
worksheet.conditional_format(
        "$A$2:$J$1000",
        {
            "type": "cell",
            "criteria": "containing",
            "value": '"Total"',
            "format": comma_format,
        },
    )
```

I would like to, whenever a row contains the word "Total" in any cell in the row, format the entire cell with `comma_format`.

The above script, however, only formats the cell containing "Total", not the entire row.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Many thanks,

Mike

Comment: In general you need to figure out how to do a complex conditional format in Excel first and then transfer it to XlsxWriter. Having said that I don't think what you want to do is possible with a single conditional format. The approach you would normally take would be to use a formula conditional format with an absolute anchor on the row. However that anchor can only be in one column per row. So you  would need to replicate the conditional format for each column in the row. As far as I know, it is more of an Excel question than a Python question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataFrame operations to get the row indices that contain the word Total like so. `rows_with_total = df[df.applymap(lambda x: True if isinstance(x, str) and 'total' in x.lower() else False).any(1)].index.to_list()`.

`applymap` iterates over all of the values in a DataFrame and applies the passed in function to each one. In this case it returns `True` if the value is a string and contains the word total, otherwise it returns `False`.

The `any` method with 1 passed in checks if any value in a row is `True` and returns a `Series` of `booleans` (`True` if any column in the row is `True` and `False` otherwise). Wrapping that part in df['that part'] filters the rows that are returned based on the `Series` `boolean` values.

Then `.index.to_list()` returns the indices of the filtered rows as a `list`.

With this list you can then do what @drew_wood suggested and loop over the rows applying the format to each one like so.

```py
for row in rows_with_total:
    worksheet.set_row(row, None, comma_format)
```

The full code

```py
rows_with_total = df[df.applymap(lambda x: True if isinstance(x, str) and 'total' in x.lower() else False).any(1)].index.to_list()
for row in rows_with_total:
    worksheet.set_row(row, None, comma_format)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store each row in your DataFrame as a list using `df.values`

You can then loop through this list, checking to see  `if 'Total' in list:`

If it is, you can then loop through every column in this row, and assign the `(row_ind,col_ind)` to your desired format.